# flutter get RuntimeException after add firebase messaging

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I config my project base on [firebase_messaging 6.0.9]https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging
after replace .Activity by .Application in manifest i get this error :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="APPLICATION_PACKAGE_NAME">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="NOTO ER DRIVER"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">



        <activity
            android:name=".Application"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCmvBBywSJtP-myH3BjGwlW8fA0xQPveRU" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

ERROR :

```
2020-01-27 12:37:30.101 16726-16726/com.notoer.notoer_driver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.notoer.notoer_driver, PID: 16726
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.notoer.notoer_driver/com.notoer.notoer_driver.Application}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.notoer.notoer_driver.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.notoer.notoer_driver.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Application Class => Android/app/src/main/java/package_name/ same with MainActivity.java

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
        import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
        import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
        import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
    }
}
```

flutter doctor :

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1130], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at G:\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (7 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at G:/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = G:/sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = G:\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1)
    • IntelliJ at G:\intelij_we_nasbi\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.4892.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 64 • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)
```

without replace .Application firebase is ok but on backgroundmessaging dont work (crash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added `.Application` in `activity` tag. 
Your Manifest file should look like this

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.snj07.flutter_notification">

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="flutter_notification">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

`Application.kt` or `Application.java` should have application specific changes. You need to create this file if its not there.

```kotlin
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"))
    }
}
```

Don't modify `MainActivity.kt` or `MainActivity.java` until it's required.

Comment: Thanks! I had renamed my `<activity android:name="..."` instead of `<application android:name="..."` like the @hadi